# Parsed JSON Data not displaying on android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a JSON string which is generated by a php file. The problem is that the JSON string is not appearing on the textview of android. can anyone explain why?

```
public class AllUsersActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;

// url to get all users list
private static String url_all_users = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_users.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_USERS = "users";
private static final String TAG_UID = "UserID";
private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";

// users JSONArray
JSONArray users = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_users);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading users in Background Thread
    new LoadAllusers().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String uid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.uid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    UserDetailsActivity.class);
            // sending uid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_UID, uid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}


/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllusers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllUsersActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading users. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All users from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_users, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All users: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // users found
                // Getting Array of users
                users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

                // looping through All users
                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_UID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_UID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    usersList.add(map);
                }
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all users
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllUsersActivity.this, usersList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_UID,
                                TAG_FIRSTNAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.uid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

this is the JSON string from the PHP file

```
{"Users":[{"0":[],"UserID":"1","FirstName":"lalawee","Email":"12345","Password":null},{"0":[],"UserID":"2","FirstName":"shadowblade721","Email":"12345","Password":null,"1":[]},{"0":[],"UserID":"3","FirstName":"dingdang","Email":"12345","Password":null,"1":[],"2":[]},{"0":[],"UserID":"4","FirstName":"solidsnake0328","Email":"12345","Password":null,"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]}],"success":1}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to narrow down the problem? Have you used the debugger to check whether request is sent and the response is received? Have you checked that the response contains the expected data? Is the response successfully converted?

Comment: Your runOnUiThread on the onPostExecuteMethod is useless because onPostExecute already run on ui thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error.

It is caused by case sensitiveness.

users --> Users

Mistake on my part. Sorry.

Thanks for trying to help me!